# Get display annotation value on mvc3 server side code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, annotations

Is there a way to get the value of an annotation in server side code? For example, I have:

```
public class Dummy
{
    [Display(Name = "Foo")]
    public string foo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Bar")]
    public string bar { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to get the value **"Foo"** on server side with out posting it back to the page, but like an attribute of the class, or something of the sort. Like a **@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Foo)** But in c# server code.

Is that possible?

Thank you.

Comment: What you mean by C# server code?

Comment: @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Foo) <-- that won't output "Foo"? Maybe you need to use the DisplayNameAttribute instead.

Comment: @sllev Sorry, I mean code behind. In an Action in a Controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
string displayName = GetDisplayName((Dummy x) => x.foo);

// ...

public static string GetDisplayName<T, U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> exp)
{
    var me = exp.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (me == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Must be a MemberExpression.", "exp");

    var attr = me.Member
                 .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false)
                 .Cast<DisplayAttribute>()
                 .SingleOrDefault();

    return (attr != null) ? attr.Name : me.Member.Name;
}
```

Or, if you want to be able to call the method against an instance and take advantage of type inference:

```
var dummy = new Dummy();
string displayName = dummy.GetDisplayName(x => x.foo);

// ...

public static string GetDisplayName<T, U>(this T src, Expression<Func<T, U>> exp)
{
    var me = exp.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (me == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Must be a MemberExpression.", "exp");

    var attr = me.Member
                 .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false)
                 .Cast<DisplayAttribute>()
                 .SingleOrDefault();

    return (attr != null) ? attr.Name : me.Member.Name;
}
```

Comment: +1, very concise. How are you able to access `attr.Name` without casting it to `Displayattribute`? `GetCustomAttributes(type, inherit)` returns `Object[]`.

Comment: First one works great, but with the latter option `GetDisplayName` does not appear as an extension on the `dummy` instance.

Comment: @Alex: I am casting it: `var attr = (DisplayAttribute)me.Member...`. (Or rather I was casting it; I've just edited the answer to use the `Cast<DisplayAttribute>()` method instead of the explicit cast.)

Comment: @Alex: The extension method needs to live in a separate, static class. I should've mentioned that.

Comment: Disregard last comment, I did not mark class as static. D'oh! I would recommend this answer over mine; it is far more robust.

Comment: Thanks! it worked like a charm... Thank @Alex-Ford or I would have probably gone with his answer...

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use reflection. Here is a sample console program that does what you want.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dummy dummy = new Dummy();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = dummy.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            IEnumerable<DisplayAttribute> displayAttributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false).Cast<DisplayAttribute>();
            foreach (DisplayAttribute displayAttribute in displayAttributes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Property {0} has display name {1}", property.Name, displayAttribute.Name);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Dummy
{
    [Display(Name = "Foo")]
    public string foo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Bar")]
    public string bar { get; set; }
}
```

This would produce the following result:

http://www.codetunnel.com/content/images/reflectresult.jpg

Comment: I updated the answer to loop through all DisplayAttributes in case a member had more than one.

Comment: A member should never have more than one because `DisplayAttribute` is annotated with `AllowMultiple = false`.

Comment: @LukeH That's fine, but I don't like making assumptions with my code ;)