# Is it possible to access the annotation value in a model?

Tags: c#, .net, annotations

Is it possible to access the value of an annotation in a model from code.

For example:

```
    [Table("TableA", Schema="SchemaA")]
    public class TableA
    {
        [Key]
        public decimal TABLE_ID { get; set; }
     }
```

Is there a way for me to get the TABLE_ID from this model by getting the "KEY" when I don't know what the actual primary key name is?

Comment: Is this any help for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047139/get-display-annotation-value-on-mvc3-server-side-code

Comment: Try these

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864662/how-i-can-find-data-annotation-attributes-and-their-parameters-using-reflection

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027613/how-to-retrieve-data-annotations-from-code

Comment: wow, I tried to make sure there was not a duplicate first but I guess it was.  Thanks for the help, this is perfect! (I also voted to close this question)